# ImplicitWait isn't working C# Appium WinAppDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, appium, winappdriver

I have the following ImplicitWait, but it's being ignored. Despite setting it to 60 seconds, when I run my code it immediately fails on the following line, without waiting. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Can we page url if it's public ?

Answer (score 0):

In Dev Express v20.2 issue has been resolved. This is because of an attribute "isOffScreen=False", in the newer version the value was True. WinAppDriver cannot interact with the element in this state and throws the error mentioned in the issue image.

Comment: What is Dev Express 20.2?